# Need help adding a loop to restart program in Python

Tags: python, loops, restart

So far this is what I have got.

```
import random

answer1=("Absolutely!")
answer2=("No way Pedro!")
answer3=("Go for it tiger.")
answer4=("There's different ways to do this.")
answer5=("Definitely not")

print("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball game-use it to answer your questions...")

questio = input("Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press Enter for an answer")

print("Shaking... \n" * 4) 

choice=random.randint(1,5)

if choice == 1:
    answer=answer1
elif choice == 2:
    answer=answer2
elif choice == 3:
      answer=answer3
elif choice == 4:
      answer=answer4

elif choice == 5:
      answer=answer5


print(answer)

restart = input("Would you like to try again?")

if restart == "yes" or "y":
```

now I need to add a loop to this so after its done it displays "Would you like to try again?". After entering yes the program starts again from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a loop like this to your code:

```
restart = ''

while restart.upper() not in ['NO', 'N', 'EXIT']:
    # ...  
    # Your code here
    # ...

    restart = input("Would you like to try again?")
```

This is essentially initializing restart as an empty string.  Then the loop is only going to start while `restart != 'NO'`.  At the end of the loop we're getting a new value from the user for `restart` so that if they say `'no'` or `'n'` the loop won't start again.

There are lots of other ways to do this, such as the inverse where you could check to see if the user entered a positive answer (`'yes'` or `'y'`) or putting a `break` if they say `'no'`.

Hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

after the import line add `while True:` indent the entire code to the while loop. then at the end go like this:

```
    restart = input("Would you like to try again?")

    if restart == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

To explain further. Continue will jump back up to the top `pass` would work as well. `break` will exit the loop. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a while loop like so:

```
import random

while True:
    answer1=("Absolutely!")
    answer2=("No way Pedro!")
    answer3=("Go for it tiger.")
    answer4=("There's different ways to do this.")
    answer5=("Definitely not")

    print("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball game-use it to answer your questions...")

    questio = input("Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press Enter for an answer ")

    print("Shaking... \n" * 4) 

    choice=random.randint(1,5)

    if choice == 1:
        answer=answer1
    elif choice == 2:
        answer=answer2
    elif choice == 3:
          answer=answer3
    elif choice == 4:
          answer=answer4

    elif choice == 5:
          answer=answer5

    print(answer)

    restart = input("Would you like to try again? ")

    if restart == "yes" or "y":
        continue

    else:
        break
```